# The script doesn't interhit a native class that can manage a object. and I have ,,all compile errors have to be fix before entering play mode"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i was creating new script ChestManager (code here:

```
public class ChestManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerController cont;

    public GameObject BookZeroPrefab;
    public GameObject BookOnePrefab;
    public GameObject BookTwoPrefab;


    void Start()
    {
        cont = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
    }

    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            OpenChest();
        }
    }

    void OpenChest()
    {
        float radnom_health = Random.Range(0,30);

        cont.Heal(radnom_health);

        float random_chance = Random.Range(0,100);

        if(random_chance <= 75)
        {
            int chance1 = Random.Range(0,2);
            for(int i = 0; i < chance1; i++){
                float book = Random.Range(0,2);
                if(book == 0) Instantiate(BookZeroPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                if(book == 1) Instantiate(BookOnePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                if(book == 2) Instantiate(BookTwoPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

            }
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

but when i try to attach this script, an error says

> The script doesn't interhit a native class that can manage a script

and also when i try to enter play mode, next error says:

> All compile errors have to be fix before entering play mode.

And now, all of the scripts, that was working goood, now says The script doesn't interhit a native class! Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider tidying up your question because the _typos, abbreviations, spelling mistakes_ (no excuse with modern browsers by the way), and _repetitiveness_ makes for a **difficult and uninteresting read**.

Comment: Guys i found out!! First i entered safe mode, then i clicked on errors, and i fixed all of them everything works good now

Comment: Great!  Don’t forget you can post that as an answer.  You can even “accept” your own post gaining reputation points in the process.  Of course make sure your answer is of SO-quality.  SO isn’t a _forum_